# react - How to open show more on a function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

I have a functional component

```
const text = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <p onClick={()=> render more?}>info</p>
    )}

const more = ({data}) => {
    return (<p>..........</p>)
}
```

Is it possible to render more component on the onClick event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you'll need a state variable. Use the state to determine whether to render more or not, and then set the state when the click happens. If you have react 16.8 or later, you can do this in a functional component with hooks:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={() => setShowMore(true)}>info</p>
      {showMore && <More data={data} />}
    </div>
  )}
}
```

Prior to 16.8, you'll need to use a class component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showMore: false,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p onClick={() => this.setState({ showMore: true})}>info</p>
        {this.state.showMore && <More data={this.props.data} />}
      </div>
    )}
  }
}
```

Comment: If older than 16.8?